# Plotting a simple linear regression model goes wrong

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, sklearn-pandas

I'd like to create a linear regression model that shows a positive correlation between BMI and Disease risk (a quantitative measure of disease one year after baseline).

The dataset is the same one from the sklearn dataset--
`import sklearn.datasets.load_diabetes`

And this is the URL
(https://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/var.select/diabetes.tab.txt)

I've imported the whole table using read_csv(args) and called it 'data'

```
df = DataFrame({'BMI': data['BMI'], 'Target': data['Y']}).sort_values('BMI')

df.plot.scatter('BMI', 'Target')

model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
model.fit(data[['BMI']], data['Y'])

x_test = np.linspace(data['BMI'].min(), data['BMI'].max())
y_pred = model.predict(x_test[:, np.newaxis])

df.plot(x_test, y_pred, linestyle=":", color="red")
```

When I try this it gives me a big error message I don't understand, why does this happen?

[image: Error Message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

[...]

df = pd.DataFrame({'BMI': data['BMI'], 'Target': data['Y']}).sort_values('BMI')

model = LinearRegression(fit_intercept=True)
model.fit(data[['BMI']], data['Y'])

x_test = np.linspace(data['BMI'].min(), data['BMI'].max())
y_pred = model.predict(x_test[:, np.newaxis])

plt.scatter(df['BMI'].values, df['Target'].values)
plt.plot(x_test, y_pred, linestyle="-", color="red")
plt.show()
```

which gives us:
[image]

The solution you had with `df.plot(x, y)` is giving you the error because this [plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html#pandas-dataframe-plot) function of the pandas dataframe only works on the dataframe it is called on. It's no general plot function like the `pyplot.plot(x, y)` [plot](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html#matplotlib-pyplot-plot) function.